# childs show using when click on parent

Tags: jquery

Child Show when click on parent.Suppose when we click on parent child show and when i click on child inner child and inner child 1 show using jquery

```
 <div id="a" class="childshow">Parent
        <div id="b" class="childshow" style="display:none">Child
            <div id="c" class="childshow" style="display:none">inner child
            </div>
            <div id="c1" class="childshow" style="display:none">inner child1
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>



    $(".childshow")click(function() {
  {
           alert("child show");



  });
```

Comment: I'd love to help, but, sadly, I don't see a question here.

Comment: every div has this class, and you are not clear enough

Comment: The syntax of your `.click()` is incorrect. It should be `.click(function() { ... });`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)** with direct child selector `>` here:

```
$(".childshow").click(function() {
    $(this).find('>.childshow').show();        
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/36SFA/)**

---

You can use `toggle()` to toggle between show and hide as well as `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent click event buble up the DOM tree:

```
$(".childshow").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('>.childshow').toggle();        
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36SFA/1/)**

Comment: my problem solved and can  you guide me if i click on parent and child shows then child hide if parent child show

Comment: I don't get what you means. Can you be more specific?

Comment: your code is working fine when click on parent its child div show and i also want when i click on parent its child already show then child hide

Comment: i know 
if if(jQuery(this).find('>.myNode').css("display")=="none"){
       $(this).find('>.myNode').show();}else{$(this).find('>.myNode').hide(); } but this not working correctly

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
$(".childshow").click(function() {
  $(this).find('*').show();        
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ns8WK/)

Comment: it should be  Children();

Comment: @waqas, did you succeed?